# FilesystemIterator to skip counting folders php

Tags: php

I wrote the below code to count the number of files in a particular path. The code works perfectly well but FilesystemIterator is also counting the directories in my path - something which I do not want. I cannot find a way how to instruct FilesystemIterator to 'skip' counting the folders.

```
<?php

$path = "\\\\192.168.10.14\\reservations"; 
$user = "user";
$pass = "pass";
$drive_letter = "Q";

system("net use ".$drive_letter.": \"".$path."\" ".$pass." /user:".$user." /persistent:no>nul 2>&1");
$location = $drive_letter.":/"; 
$fi = new FilesystemIterator($path, FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
$fileCount = iterator_count($fi);
echo $fileCount;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem as follows:

```
<?php

$path = "\\\\192.168.10.14\\reservations"; 
$user = "user";
$pass = "user";
$drive_letter = "Q";
system("net use ".$drive_letter.": \"".$path."\" ".$pass." /user:".$user." /persistent:no>nul 2>&1");
$location = $drive_letter.":/"; 
$objects = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path);
$fileCount = iterator_count($objects);
echo $fileCount;
?>
```